# mysql select * from table group by id with rollup

Tags: mysql, rollup

I try to select from my table and rollup to get the Total but i failed. Here is my table and values
[image]

and the result i want like this

[image]

is this possible?
my query :

```
select * from mytable group by id with rollup;
```

But my query failed to get the rollup values, please show me the way thanks

Comment: you have to use aggregator function sum on columns

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
select id,sum(qty),sum(import),sum(loss),sum(results) 
from mytable group by id asc with rollup;
```

Comment: Thanks @reds is really helpful

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like below

```
    select coalesce(CAST(id as CHAR(50)),'Total'),
max(local),sum(import),sum(loss),sum(results)  from mytable group by id asc with rollup
```